# VB.NET How to Upload of user profile in Online Storage

Tags: vb.net

Hello I have a question. Right now I can upload user Avatar to database then the location will be saved in my Computer locally. So my question is  how do I make it globally? How can I upload and retrieve User profile Globally?

Comment: What do you mean by upload and retrieve globally.  What is "globally" in this context.  Question needs a whole heap more info

Comment: I mean when I go to another computer and open the application then login the userinfo and user Avatar will be login there and when I go to Another computer and login the userinfo and avatar will be displayed there too

Comment: Ok, well this is going to be pretty board then.  You are going to need some sort of storage solution to store the user profile and/or avatar.  There a literally thousands of options on this and will somewhat depend on your environment.  What kind of app are you developing? Web, winform, mobile.... and so on.  A database of some nature would probably be your best starting point

Comment: I'm trying to develop a winform. What storage do i used to store the user profile and avatar?

Comment: Well that 100% upto you and your requirements.  I whole hearty suggest the first thing to do would be look at your requirements, research the tools available and pick the best match.  No one here is going to give you any specific recommendations

Comment: @Hursey can you give me some example of an Online Storage? Is it GoDaddy? Or Hostinger? or Google Drive? I'm sorry i really have no idea on how to store the User Avatar Online but right now i can store User Avatar Locally

Comment: @Hursey Okay I got it, i searched something and found some answer  thanks bro for replaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar in the past, years ago. Considering you code in VB.NET WinForms, it should be easy for you to do VB.NET web forms.

Get a cheap hosting to practice (Windows) or set a local IIS, post the file to a service, and the code below (which I used years ago) will allow you to upload a file to a remote server. This code goes on the SERVER SIDE:

```
Dim Files As HttpFileCollection
            Files = Request.Files
            Dim ext As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Files(0).FileName)
            Dim FileName = "MyFileID" & ext
            Files(0).SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/avatars/" & FileName))
```

You will need to invest some time in learning how to work with web services. Also, you will need to integrate validations, otherwise anyone could POST to your service.